# MemoryError in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame with 753 rows and 5124 columns. Im trying to find all possible combinations between the columns using the code below. Obviously, this requires a lot of memory and I'm getting "MemoryError" when running the code. Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem? Thank you for any advice!

import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

```
df3 = df1.join(df2)

all_combinations = list(combinations(df3.columns, 2)) + \
                   list(combinations(df3.columns, 3))







MemoryError
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? (BTW, the number of rows is irrelevant to your question.)

Comment: Is `combinations` from `itertools`? Then don't force the result into a `list`. That would use a lot of memory.

Comment: Thank you Klaus, and yes, I'm using combinations from itertools!

Comment: In addition, to answer your question Ami, I have around 5000 columns containing rows with True or False. I want to test each combination of columns where True is equal to True for each row

Comment: This is the whole code im working with:                                                                    df3 = df1.join(df2)

all_combinations = list(combinations(df3.columns, 2)) + \
                   list(combinations(df3.columns, 3))

for combination in all_combinations:

   df3["".join(list(combination))] = df3[list(combination)].product(axis=1).astype(bool)